# Probability of two people belong to two different groups in a random partition.

Tags: probability, set-partition

Partition $k$ people into $t$ groups of sizes $k_1,\ldots,k_t$ where $k = \sum_{i=1}^t k_i$ randomly. What is the probability that two people belong to two different groups?

I find that the answer is roughly
$$1-
\sum_{i=1}^t\ \frac{k_i^2}{k^2}~.
$$

However, can we have a more precise formula?

Comment: This looks more like the probability that they belong to the same group.  Is there a typo?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways to assign two people to the same group is $$(k-2)!\sum_{i=1}^t\binom{k_i}{2}$$  since there are $\binom{k_i}{2}$ ways to pick their positions in group $i$.  The total number of ways to assign the people is $\frac{k!}{2}$.  The probability works out to be $$1-\sum_{i=1}^t\frac{k_i(k_i-1)}{k(k-1)},$$ very close to your estimate.